# Azure DevOps - How to receive title of work items (product backlog items) in query api?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I could not find any direct API which can be called with tag as input and returns all the items associated with that tag
so i created a query in UI and calling this query using this api call:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_apis/wit/wiql/{queryId}?api-version=6.0
```

But it is only returning item id and url, i want title as well in the response, how can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the REST API for Wiql cannot directly the titles of the work items.

As a workaround, you can try like as below:

1. Install the "[**Wiql to OData**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-eswm.wiql-to-odata)" extension to your Azure DevOps organization.
2. Open the work item query you created. Make sure you have added the **`Title`** column on the query page.

   [image]
3. Open the menu list of on the query page, and select the option "**`Translate To OData`**". From the pop-up window, you can see the OData query translated from the Wiql. You can edit the OData query (if require). Then click the "Copy query" button to copy the OData query.

   [image]
4. Use the **GET** method to call the OData query. From the returned result, you can see the titles of the work items.

   [image]

For more details, you can reference the following documents:

- [**Extensions and manage queries**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-support-integration-cross-service-extensions?view=azure-devops#extensions-and-manage-queries)
- [**Query your work tracking data using OData Analytics**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/wit-analytics?view=azure-devops)

Comment: As of now we don't have any control over azure devops org we are using so we can not install any extension.

Comment: Hi @user10916892, You can try to contact the organization owner or PCA to help to install the extension.

Comment: Thanks, for me this is the answer, working just fine.